# Android application - Logging causing error

Tags: android, string, sqlite, passwords

Hi I am working with my application project.. It just happen that after I click on the login button, an error message pops out saying that Sorry! The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. What is the error of this? please help thanks

This was my code for the data base of the user..

```
package com.gomez.android;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class dbuser{


public static final String user_name = "username";
public static final String user_password = "password";
public static final String row_id = "_id";

private static final String TAG = "UdbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper UdbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase Udb;

/**
 * Database creation sql statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table pages (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "username text not null, password text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserAccount";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "User";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private Context context = null;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pages");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public dbuser(Context cntxt) {
    this.context = cntxt;
    UdbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    Udb = UdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    UdbHelper.close();
}

public long createaccount(String username, String password) 
{
    Udb = UdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(user_name, username);
    initialValues.put(user_password, password);

    return Udb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean Login(String username, String password)throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = Udb.rawQuery(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{username,password});
    if (mCursor != null){
        if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

and this was my login page code.....

```
package com.gomez.android;

import com.gomez.android.dbuser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class login extends Activity{
//Declare views
private EditText uname;
private EditText pword;
private Button btnlogin;
private Button btncancel;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set Activity Layout
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    //Get EditText and Button References
    uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_enter);
    btncancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    //set Click Listener
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check Login
            final String username = uname.getText().toString();
            final String password = pword.getText().toString();


            dbuser users = new dbuser(login.this);
            users.open();
            if(users.Login(username, password)){
                    if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(username)&& password.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(login.this,"Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(login.this, firstpage.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(login.this,"Invalid Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    users.close();
                }
            }


    });

    btncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //close application
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: do not underestimate the power of the LogCat!

Comment: Use your logcat, also you need to put relevant code, no one is going to read through all that code with no direction from the logcat

Comment: Please post your stack trace output.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure what the problem is with your code since you didn't provide any information from the LogCat, but it is possible that `getWriteableDatabase()` is returning a cached database when running the application (I often ran into this problem when implementing and testing a database for the first time).

To ensure this is not the problem, go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> [Your Application] -> Clear Data, before running the application from Eclipse. This is an easy way to ensure you are working with your most up-to-date implementation during the early stages of implementing/testing the database.

This very well might not be the problem, but it is one of those things that you wouldn't expect to be the issue (which often leads to hours of frustration), so I thought I'd bring it up :).

Comment: Mr. Alex Lockwood, here is the LogCat information:
01-16 13:18:39.762: D/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
thank you